# flutter setState: how to update with array?

Tags: flutter

I have an array of small objects which is used to display List. What I'm doing now:

```
final _wordsList = <Word>[];
String triggerRerender;

getSharedText() async {
    var sharedData = await platform.invokeMethod("getSharedText");
    if (sharedData != null) {
      _wordsList.add(Word(sharedData));

      setState(() {
        triggerRerender = sharedData;
      });
    }
  }
```

and that feels wild. Shouldn't I be triggering rerender by changing array, not by some "trigger" primitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have a `triggerRenderer`, I think.

Here's what the docs say:

> Whenever you change the internal state of a State object, make the
>   change in a function that you pass to setState

Just update the data **inside** of the `setState` function:

```
final _wordsList = <Word>[];

getSharedText() async {
  var sharedData = await platform.invokeMethod("getSharedText");
  if (sharedData != null) {
    setState(() {
      _wordsList.add(Word(sharedData))
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That has appeared so, thank you. Funny thing, that it also works, if I do:
```_wordsList.add(Word(sharedData));
      setState(() {
      });```. Hence seems like `setState()` doesn't look on what happens inside it's callback

Comment: setState triggers the build() function. You can always set state and trigger the function later, but it's not recommended, because of the asynchronous way in which these things are executed, I think